# Nested IF and OR formulas in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm trying to get a formula to function in excel (I17) and am missing something, but I can't quite tell where.

Current Formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(H17),”0”,(IF(ISBLANK(J17), IF(OR(H17<G17,H17=G17),"0","1"), IF(OR(H17<J17,H17=J17),"0","1"))))
```

Essentially, if `H17` is blank, then `I17` should be 0.

If `H17` is not blank, then the formula needs to first look to see if `J17` is blank.

If `J17` is blank, the formula needs to compare `H17` to `G17`. If `H17` is less than or equal to `G17`, the formula should produce a `0`. If `H17` is greater than `G17`, it should produce a 1.

If `J17` is not blank, the formula needs to compare `H17` to `J17`. If `H17` is less than or equal to `J17`, the formula should produce a `0`. If `H17` is greater than `J17`, it should produce a `1`.

Comment: What is it doing that is incorrect?

Comment: Also realize the `ISBLANK()` returns false if there is a formula in the cell that returns a null string.

Comment: also the stylized quotes, `”0”` will cause an issue.  Numbers should not have quotes around them.

Comment: `OR(H17<G17,H17=G17)` can be simplified: `H17<=G17`

Comment: Scott, thank you! It was the quotation marks around the 0 and 1 which were throwing the error. I've just tested it otherwise and it appears to be working.

I'll also take this opportunity to simplify the OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(H17),0,IF(ISBLANK(J17),IF(H17<=G17,0,1),IF(H17<=J17,0,1)))
```

Does your version of Excel support `IFS`? I think this will do the same thing, not that it's necessarily that much easier to understand:

```
=IFS(ISBLANK(H18),0,ISBLANK(J18),IF(H18<=G18,0,1),H18<=J18,0,TRUE,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify down to:

```
=SUM(IF(H1="",0,IF(J1="",H1>G1,H1>J1)))
```

---

This will result in either `0`, `TRUE/FALSE`, or `TRUE/FALSE`. We can convert the boolean responses to 1s and 0s by taking the sum.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
=(H1<>"")*(((J1<>"")*(H1>J1))+((J1="")*(H1>G1)))
```